# Windows 8.1 can't access internet through VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1

In my university we should connect to VPN for access to the Internet, Every things was okay when I used Windows 7, But recently I have upgrated to Windows 8.1, In this windows I have a trouble with that VPN, When I connect to VPN, it connects fine and appears no error, But there is no Internet access (But I can access Internet with same VPN same server same configuration same ... in Windows 7).

Can any one point me out how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you ping (from `cmd` try `ping 8.8.8.8`) Google's DNS? The reason I ask is to see if it's a DNS issue or not, before diving down deeper into other possibilities.

Comment: @nerdwaller I can't ping any hosts, it gives a `can not resolve host` error

Comment: A common issue from the past has been `use default gateway on remote network`, which is under VPN > Properties > Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) > Properties > Advanced, then the above checkbox.  Is that currently checked or unchecked?  More often than not, unchecking it fixes the troubles.

Comment: @ABFORCE - How do you connect to the VPN.  If you are using a client, i.e. OpenVPN, run the installer again.

Comment: @nerdwaller; I tried with both checked and unchecked! but no luch

Comment: @Ramhound I connect using Windows 8.1 native utilities

Comment: @nerdwaller What to do if it is a DNS issue. I am getting the same limited internet connectivity when connected to a VPN and trouble shooting the problem tells me that my primary DNS isn't working.

Comment: This may not be your issue, but it was mine. I had the same exact issue where it was not the vpn that was a problem but the network stack was damaged http://oyam.ca/blog/2011/11/windows-miniports/